# How to get an array of object from firestore in appscript

Tags: database, firebase, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-firestore

I have a set of documents in Firestore in this format. Questions array will 10 questions.

[image]

I want to get the data of questions field: one row for one question

[image]

I do I code in the appscript to perform this

This is my code so far (for one document only)

```
function test(){
  const firestore = getFirestore();
  
  var query =  firestore.getDocument("QuestionCollection/test").fields;
  var data =  {};
       
  data.subject = query.subject;
  data.questions= query.questions;
  
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  
  for(i = 0 ; i < 10 (no. of question); i++){
    const row = [data.questions[i].answer, data.questions[i].difficulty];
    sheet.appendRow(row);
  }  
}
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'answer' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your sample data in the image, it seems that the array length of `questions` is 2. But at the for loop, the end index of loop is `9`. I think that by them, such error occurs.
- When you want to put the value of "Serial", it is required to add the value for putting to Spreadsheet.
- In your script, `appendRow` is used in a loop. In this case, the process cost becomes high.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Your for loop is modified as follows.

From:

```
for(i = 0 ; i < 10 (no. of question); i++){
  const row = [data.questions[i].answer, data.questions[i].difficulty];
  sheet.appendRow(row);
}
```

To:

```
var values = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.questions.length; i++) {
  const row = [i + 1, data.questions[i].answer, data.questions[i].difficulty];
  values.push(row);
}
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

- For the end index of loop, the array length is used.

#### Reference:

- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (line 66, file "Code")```
This error show up at the last line, If I try to remove the last line and use appendRow instead, nothing happens. The script sees ```data.questions.length``` as 0. If I manually give a value instead of length ```data.questions[i].answer, data.questions[i].difficulty``` these become undefined

Comment: @Nehal Thank you for replying. From your replying, I'm worry that your `query` might have no values. Because if `query` has the values in your sample image, I can confirm that  the script works. So can I ask you about the values of `query` in your script? If you can do, please provide the sample value of `query` in your script? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: there is vaues in the Firestore documents but nothing is happening in the AppScript

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `there is vaues in the Firestore documents but nothing is happening in the AppScript`. In your situation, you have still not retrieved the values from Cloud Firestore. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't query the `.fields` property directly (because your data isn't converted properly). Assuming you're using **v28**+ of the library, your code should look something like this:

```js
function test(){
  const firestore = getFirestore();
  
  const query = firestore.getDocument("QuestionCollection/test").obj;  // Don't use .fields here
  
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const values = [["Serial", "Answer", "Difficulty"]];  // Init 2D array with Header row

  // Loop through each question in the array and extract necessary values to construct Data rows
  for (const question of query.questions){
    values.push([query.questions.indexOf(question) + 1, question.answer, question.difficulty]);
  }

  // Replace 1, 1 below with coords of "Serial" header cell
  const range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length);
  range.setValues(values);
  
  // sheet.getRange(subjRow, subjCol).setValue(query.subject);  // Add location for Subject data
}
```

I saw that you wanted "Serial" to represent "Question number", so I added that column to the header and data rows.

As Tanaike mentioned, there's a *huge* performance hit for writing to the spreadsheet in a loop, so it's better if you set up a 2D array of values to write all at once using [`range.setValues(array2D)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues). Ideally, you'll want to [minimize the calls](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices) to the Spreadsheet API.

**Disclaimer:** I'm an active contributor to the [FirestoreGoogleAppsScript](https://github.com/grahamearley/FirestoreGoogleAppsScript) library.